# What does "with a toss of head" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> With perhaps slight toss of head, he told her to begone.

In such kind of sentence, what would "toss of head" mean in this context?
To inform you further context is about two people arguing with each other. But I can't tell whether it is that common "he moved his head to the upwards with anger" or "said things without thinking twice"

Comment: The second meaning. "Slight toss of (his) head" is a small, dismissive gesture.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about the meaning of a specific sequence of words that would never be used in that exact form by any native speakers.

Answer (score 1):

As quoted, it isn't good modern English grammar - it should be "**a** slight toss of **the** head", which is an idiomatic way to describe moving the head backwards, as opposed to a 'nod' which is a movement forwards.

[This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=toss%20of%20head%2C%20toss%20of%20the%20head%2C%20nod%20of%20head%2C%20nod%20of%20the%20head&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoss%20of%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoss%20of%20the%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnod%20of%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnod%20of%20the%20head%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctoss%20of%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoss%20of%20the%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnod%20of%20head%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnod%20of%20the%20head%3B%2Cc0) shows that both 'nod' and 'toss' are usually used with a determiner. The few uses without date back 80 years or more.

A slight nod of the head is used as a gesture to point someone towards something, or to instruct them to do something you have previously discussed. A slight toss of the head is sometimes used as a dismissive gesture, telling someone to leave.

Comment: So it doesn't have any idiomatic meaning like acting impulsively, thoughtlessly?

Comment: You do need the article before "slight" but you don't need a determiner in front of "head". Dorthy Parker wrote in Standard of Living, "She added that everybody had a silver-fox coat. She went on, **with perhaps a slight toss of head**, to declare that she herself wouldn’t be caught dead in silver fox." It does sound a bit old fashioned without it though.

Comment: @rollsdey_77 Not that i'm aware of.

Comment: @ColleenV Great if you want to sound like you're living in the 1940s.

Comment: It depends on the context. [I thought, if people are going to think of me as someone that’s always on holiday, I’ll damn well be that person (toss of head mandatory).](https://www.fashionmenow.co.uk/2018/10/a-long-weekend-in-mallorca/) There are a lot of choices other than just "the" though - "her head" is more common if you look at the Ngrams for "toss of * head".